# Setting user culture at signin with sfDoctrineGuardPlugin

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony-1.4, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

How do you set the user culture during the signin process which is handled by the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin? Each user can set their preferred language which is stored in the sfGuardUserProfile table.

Originally I had thought about overriding the `executeSignin()` function by doing something similar to this:

```
public function executeSignin(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->getUser()->setCulture($this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getProfile()->getLanguage());
  parent::executeSignin($request);
}
```

but obviously I can't do that since I don't have access to the GuardUser object before the parent function is executed.

Then I thought about creating a `postExectute()` function similar to this:

```
public function postExecute()
{
  if($this->getUser()->isAuthenticated()){
    //SET USER CULTURE
  }
}
```

but again this can't work because the signin function does a redirect so `postExecute()` will never run.

I cannot put my logic to set the culture on the default page after login, because the user is not always redirected to the same page or even the same module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will go on something easier than re-create the action.

In your file `/apps/[your app]/lib/user/myUser.class.php` which extends `sfGuardSecurityUser`:

You can override the `signIn` function like that :

```
public function signIn($user, $remember = false, $con = null)
{
  parent::signin($user, $remember, $con);

  $this->setCulture($user->getProfile()->getLanguage());
}
```

So every time a user is log in, it will have its culture setted.

Comment: That's a nice one too. I got used to overriding the action as I'm usually fiddling with the redirections made after a successful signin.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski it always depends on how much work you have to do *around* the signIn method :)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. Also as a bonus I didn't realize I could omit `getGuardUser()` and call `getProfile()` directly. This is great.

Comment: @Zach you can do that because `$user` is an object of sfGuardUser, otherwise your method was ok.

Answer (score 1):

Your first guess is a right approach, just need a change ;)

Instead of calling the parent `executeSignin()` write your own signin action (e.g. copy the one used by the plugin). Then add the line you need

```
$this->getUser()->setCulture($this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getProfile()->getLanguage());
```

just before the redirection is made - so when you already have the Profile assigned to your user session.

You can change the setting in `settings.yml` to have sfDoctrineGuard use the new action:

```
all:
  .settings:
    login_module:          myCleverModule
    login_action:          signinMyUser
```

You can also create a folder in your `app/appName/modules/sfGuardAuth/actions`, create an `actions.class.php` there and put your `executeSignin()` function in this file. It will automatically override the original from the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. I have accepted j0k's answer since it is more elegant for my current needs. If, in the future, I need to add more logic or tweak the default functionality, your solution would definitely be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to the sfGuardUser object before authentication. This doesn't mean you don't have access to an sfUser from an [action](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfComponent#method_getuser) instance which is what you need.

Does the line

```
$this->getUser()->isAuthenticated()
```

not suggest to you that a user is not necessarily authenticated when you call it.

So if that line doesn't set the culture, look somewhere else. I'd start with checking if the culture is present in the request in some form that might override your previous line so try swapping those.

In Symfony, the sfUser represents a PHP session which is started before the user signs in and not a user. You try to manipulate the session data via sfUser::setAttribute so that should work.

Comment: I realize I have access to sfUser to set the culture, however I don't know what culture to set it to until I have access to the sfGuardUser object since the user stores their language preference in the sfGuardUserProfile table. As for the `isAuthenticated()` call... this `postExecute()` function is in the sfGuardAuth module which also handles signout so I need to check and make sure the user is authenticated before I try to access the sfGuardUser object or I will get errors.

Comment: So then why don't you wrap the line that tries to set the culture in the first snippet into the conditional in the second snippet? I mean NOT in postExecute but in place (in the first snippet).